# Wait for page called by $.get to finish executing before resuming execution in call back function

Tags: jquery, ext.net

We want to implement an innovative UI. Effectively what we're doing is as follows:

- When the user clicks on a menu item link, a $.get(url) is invoked and we are pulling out the HTML content of the page referenced in the url.
- We then take that content and populate it in an output div and prior to population, we remove whatever content of that output div was.

This is a cut down version of what we are actually doing but it serves the purpose of illustrating what problem I am currently facing.

Effectively, when the page getting pulled using $.get(url) contains plain HTML, I have no problems. However, if the page getting pulled using $.get(url) contains Ext.NET code, then I don't get anything returned back.

What is effectively happening is that the Ext.NET code is itself calling other scripts and inserting elements in the DOM. This causes a problem because my code execution goes to the callback function **before** Ext.NET has had time to insert the content I'm trying to access.

So a naive attempt to resolve this problem would be to wait until Ext.NET has finished populating the page and then return code execution to the callback function. The question is how do I do this? Is there actually a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do i.e. ensure that $.get(url) has fully run its course so that my output div is populated properly?

I guess I could down the route of using an iFrame but I would like to avoid that if possible because it would increase the complexity of an already complicated interface.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting the html generated by the rendered Ext.NET Components should be possible, although I think you'll be missing another important aspect... the DOM events attached to each of those Components.

What you'll need is any html sent in the original payload PLUS and the JavaScript used to generate the page AND you'll need to execute that JavaScript on your parent page. Just bringing over the html is not going to get you much.

If you are running Ext.NET on the parent page, you might want to investigate using the  functionality available on any Container type. The base functionality of  is to fetch the remote page/html + script and execute that script.

The following example demonstrates.

**Example**

```
<ext:Panel runat="server" Title="Example">
    <AutoLoad Url="example.html" /> 
</ext:Panel>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Geoffroy but now I've gone down the iframe route which kind of works for now but I'll keep your advice in mind. I won't mark it as answer as I havent' tried it but I'll upvote it as it might be an avenue worth exploring.

Comment: Actually that won't help for what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
async: false,
```

so do the call like this..

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET", // Don't need to declare this..
  url: 'url.html',
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
     // Do something with the returned data..
  }
});
```

Comment: @david1dMcLean: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either i.e. I get the same results.

Comment: I have not used EXT.net yet.. but is is there a way to make it wait till the dom is loaded? not sure how that would work as the page you are calling it from is already loaded.. *thinking* OK how about setting an variable to true once the external page has been loaded... the js on the external page loads but does not fire until the value of the variable is set to true. This would mean everything is loaded.. you might need to implement via custom events-> http://www.truerwords.net/articles/web-tech/custom_events.html -is old but I believe it still works (not tried in new IE or FF thought).

Comment: @david1dMcLean: Thanks for you input. I've about that plan as well but I think that I will need to go down the route of iframes and I'm already experiencing horrible stuff.

Comment: ohh no not iframes! lol Good luck man.. I would personally look at the events stuff first I think. would be a nice solution across the app.

Comment: @david1dMcLean: Well iframes are something that I've been able to avoid so far in my professional career. However, they almost do what I want them to do but yes I feel dirty.